# c++ dependency injection to test a class that class system calls

Tags: c++, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I am trying to use template dependency injection to test a C++ class that uses C system calls to operate over a file descriptor. The ideia is to have an abstract class and an instance to wrap the system calls like read(), write(), etc. Then I use a mock to test my target class.
The abstract class and system calls looks like: (I am going to omit parameters to be clear)

```
class OSCall{
    read()=0;
    write()=0
};
class DefaultOSCall : public OSCall{
    read(){...}
    write(){...}
}
```

Later I inject the OSCall in the class I want to use it:

```
template<typename OSCall>
class FD{
    public:
        OSCall osCall_;
        OSCall &GetOSCall(){return osCall_;}

        read(){osCall_.read()}
        write(){osCall_.write()}
}
```

Now if I want to use a mock to test my FD class I just need to pass my mock in the template paramenter and get the mock instance using GetOsCall.

Let's say I want to use the FD as a member of another class:

```
template<typename OSCall>
class User{
    public:
        DoSomething(){fd_.read();.......}
        OSCall &GetMemberOSCall(){return fd_.GetOSCall()}
    private:
        FD<OSCall> fd_;
}
```

If I want to test the user with a mock, I can get the OSCall instance using the GetMemberOSCall, it works, but is it one of the best ways to do it? In the end I want to inject a mock to a class member and expect the return values of the member's mock. I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you rename `GetMemberOSCall()` as just `getOSCall()`.

This would seem to enable this to be used in conjunction with generic templates whose template classes need to implement a `getOSCall()` method, and you would be able to instantiate this template with either `FD<OScall>`, or `User<OScall>`. Seems to be a bit more flexible approach.

Comment: I think I got your point, however, I thought in another question. Let's say I want to have to members using the OSCall wrapper:
`template<typename OSCall>
class User{
    ......
    private:
        FD<OSCall> fd_;
        OtherClass<OSCall> other_;
}`
In this case, in order to be able to mock the oscall return types I would need to access the OSCall instance from both FD and OtherClass. The quick response would be to have to methods to get both instances. Does it sound good practice?

Comment: Sounds to me like OSCall should really be a std::shared_ptr, or something similar, so that there would only be one OSCall instance shared by all class methods; and then it wouldn't matter. Alternatively, use inheritance instead of class members, with a virtual OSCall base class.